# String function - convert singular to plural

Tags: c++, string

I'm writing a function to change nouns to plurals
every condition is working great except words ending with y
it should work like input : fly output :flies
but the output comes out as : flis

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void change_to_plural(char* input_string, char* output_string) // changing to plural
{
    int n;
    n = strlen(input_string);
    if (input_string[n - 1] == 'y') //ends with y
    {
        input_string[n + 2] = '\0';
        input_string[n - 1] = 'i';
        input_string[n] = 'e';
        input_string[n + 1] = 's';

    }
    if (input_string[n - 1] == 's' || ((input_string[n - 2] == 's') && (input_string[n - 1] == 'h'))) // ends with s or sh
    {
        input_string[n] = 'e';
        input_string[n + 1] = 's';
        input_string[n + 2] = '\0';
    }
    else //other cases
    {
        input_string[n] = 's';
        input_string[n + 1] = '\0';
    }
    output_string = input_string;
    n = strlen(input_string);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << output_string[i];
}


void main() {

    char in[10], out[10];
    int k;
    cout << "How many words would you like to try ? ";
        cin >> k;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a word : ";
            cin >> in;
            cout << "Its plural is : ";
            change_to_plural(in, out);
            cout << endl;
        }
    cout << endl;
}
```

run sample

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accessing `input_string` out of bounds?

Comment: are you using std::string or the C char array string?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Well, it is. You can copy it to your favorite IDE, compile it, and it will reproduce the issue right away.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It wasn't when I wrote the comment. You can see when and how a post was changed by clicking the "edited XXX time ago" link below its body.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sorry about that, then. I assumed that the code was posted as it is now. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **else** if statement (added all caps comment where it was missing, hope that you will notice it). So, because of that, it still goes to the "other cases" branch.

```
if (input_string[n - 1] == 'y') //ends with y
{
    input_string[n + 2] = '\0';
    input_string[n - 1] = 'i';
    input_string[n] = 'e';
    input_string[n + 1] = 's';

}
// MISSING ELSE HERE!!!!
else if (input_string[n - 1] == 's' || ((input_string[n - 2] == 's') && (input_string[n - 1] == 'h'))) // ends with s or sh
{
    input_string[n] = 'e';
    input_string[n + 1] = 's';
    input_string[n + 2] = '\0';
}
else //other cases
{
    input_string[n] = 's';
    input_string[n + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: but there is an else right under what you wrote

Comment: @Trix In his corrected version, yes, but not in your wrong one.

Comment: @Trix, It is present in my post, since I added it there. It isn't there in your original snippet.

Comment: @BaummitAugen ohh, sorry about that.